# How to get smooth scroll with Logitech mouse

Tags: mouse, logitech, scrolling, mouse-scroll

I have a Logitech M600 mouse working in Ubuntu 20.04. I would like to have smooth scrolling instead of "discrete scrolling", i.e. the same type of scrolling I have in my touchpad. How can I do this? Note that I am not talking about changing the acceleration, the speed, the inertia, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not seem like a hot topic, but in case someone (myself in the future?) wants to get smooth scroll with Logitech on Ubuntu, I was able to make it work following [this](https://rhtenhove.nl/blog/hires-scrolling-logitech/). Summary:

1. Install [Solaar](https://github.com/pwr-Solaar/Solaar). You need Solaar to access your mouse and change its configuration, in case it does not have "precision scroll" enabled by default (as was in my case).
2. Run Solaar and enable *Scroll Wheel High Resolution*
   [image]
3. Now your mouse will scroll incredibly fast. To fix this, create a file in `/etc/udev/hwdb.d/71-logitech-mice.hwdb` with the following content:

   ```
   mouse:*:name:*M600*:
       MOUSE_WHEEL_CLICK_ANGLE=1
       MOUSE_WHEEL_CLICK_COUNT=360
   ```

   Note that the first line is related to the name of your mouse, which you can find using the `xinput` command. I don't exactly know the syntax, the `*` are there probably to match any name with this structure. I just put this and it worked. You can customize these numbers, in my case I changed the `360` by `222` which resulted in a better scrolling.
4. Run

   ```
   sudo systemd-hwdb update
   sudo udevadm trigger /dev/input/event*
   ```

   and *voilà*.

This was *restart persistent* for me, i.e. after restarting my PC it was still working. However, **it is not *mouse power off and on again* persistent**, i.e. after you power off the mouse the scroll is not nice. To get it back just run Solaar.